# How can i get the Database Driver from an existing EntityManager?

Tags: java, jpa, entitymanager

In my application, i should know, which database driver i use.
This can be in case to case another. (H2 or Postgres)

Is there a way to check if it's an H2? Because H2 doesn't have the same tables.

cheers
K.Hunn

Comment: Do you intend to query the postgres `information_schema` or something like that?

Comment: This might also be dependent on your `JPA` implementation. Which is it?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible but i am not quite sure if it is any solution to any problem.

You can get driver name from `java.sql.Connection` like:

```
conn.getMetaData().getDriverName();
```

or

```
conn.getMetaData().getDriverVersion();
```

**BUT:** the tricky part here is how to get the connection because it is JPA provider specific stuff. Here is how it goes with OpenJPA:

First you need unwrapped (= implementation specific) entity manager:

```
OpenJPAEntityManager unWrappedEm = OpenJPAPersistence.cast(em);
```

So you have to know what it is. After that you can obtain the connection like this (still in OpenJPA):

```
Connection conn = (Connection)unWrappedEm.getConnection();
```

From `javadoc` for `EntityManager` method `<T> T unwrap(java.lang.Class<T> cls)`

> Return an object of the specified type to allow access to the
>   provider-specific API. If the provider's EntityManager implementation
>   does not support the specified class, the PersistenceException is
>   thrown.